# pygame window collison bug

Tags: python, window, pygame

I made a moveable white tank using the arrow keys. I made some collision detection so that the 'tank' wouldn't go out the screen. The only places where the collision doesn't work is when the 'tank' is positioned near the corners and when pressed up or down respective to top and bottom, it falls out of the window. Any ideas how to fix this? Collision code is in **def drawtank().**

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30
WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
TANK_SIZE = 20

BLACK = (0  ,0  ,0  )
WHITE = (255,255,255)

def drawArena():
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)

def drawTank(tank):
    if tank.bottom > WINDOW_HEIGHT:
        tank.bottom = WINDOW_HEIGHT
    elif tank.top < 0:
        tank.top = 0
    elif tank.right > WINDOW_WIDTH:
        tank.right = WINDOW_WIDTH
    elif tank.left < 0:
        tank.left = 0
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, tank)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    global DISPLAYSURF
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Tanks')

    tankX = 200
    tankY = 200
    tankX_change = 0

    tank = pygame.Rect(tankX, tankY, TANK_SIZE, TANK_SIZE)

    drawArena()
    drawTank(tank)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys_pressed[K_LEFT]:
            tankX -= 20

        if keys_pressed[K_RIGHT]:
            tankX += 20

        if keys_pressed[K_UP]:
            tankY -=20

        if keys_pressed[K_DOWN]:
            tankY += 20


        tank = pygame.Rect(tankX, tankY, TANK_SIZE, TANK_SIZE)

        drawArena()
        drawTank(tank)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `if/elif's` for each  possibility, `elif tank.right > WINDOW_WIDTH` is only evaluated of the previous if and elif is False so you miss when the tank in in the corner:

```
def drawTank(tank):
    if tank.bottom > WINDOW_HEIGHT:
        tank.bottom = WINDOW_HEIGHT
    elif tank.top < 0:
        tank.top = 0
    if tank.right > WINDOW_WIDTH: # need an if here
        tank.right = WINDOW_WIDTH
    elif tank.left < 0:
        tank.left = 0
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, tank)
```

You don't need the one extra if as the tank cannot be at the top and bottom of the screen simultaneously.

There is an easier way though:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)) # add this 
screen_rect = screen.get_rect() # this
```

Now your code is:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30
TANK_SIZE = 20
BLACK = (0  ,0  ,0  )
WHITE = (255,255,255)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen_rect=screen.get_rect()
def drawArena():
    screen.fill(BLACK)

def drawTank(tank):
    tank.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, tank)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.display.set_caption('Tanks')
    tankX = 200
    tankY = 200
    tankX_change = 0

    tank = pygame.Rect(tankX, tankY, TANK_SIZE, TANK_SIZE)

    drawArena()
    drawTank(tank)
    ......
```

Comment: very nice and clean. TYVM

Comment: No worries, it is a rough draft but hopefully should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pygame.  But, could there be more than one arrow key pressed prior to a call to drawTank?  If so, the fact that things are happening close to the corners suggests to me that perhaps the tank is moved to a position to the left of the box and below the box (for example).  Then the `if` ... `elif` that you call will only correct one of those errors.

If that's it, just turn every `elif` in `drawtank` to `if`:

```
def drawTank(tank):
    if tank.bottom > WINDOW_HEIGHT:
        tank.bottom = WINDOW_HEIGHT
    if tank.top < 0:
        tank.top = 0
    if tank.right > WINDOW_WIDTH:
        tank.right = WINDOW_WIDTH
    if tank.left < 0:
        tank.left = 0
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, tank)
```